# wrong result in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, binary-search-tree, codeblocks

I've never come across this kind of error before. When I compiled in CodeBlock, my code worked just fine, but when I copy the code into VS (2015 community), it showed only two numbers. (I was printing a binary tree)

and this is the code for binary search tree, and it worked fine in CodeBlocks but not in Visual Studio

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
struct node
{
    int data;
    int balance_factor;
    node* left_linker;
    node* right_linker;
};

struct binary_tree
{
    node* root;
};

void init_tree(binary_tree& in_tree);
node* create_new_node(int data);
void insert_node(int in_data,binary_tree& in_tree);
node* insert_recursively(int in_data,node* in_root);
bool tree_empty(binary_tree& in_tree);
void print_tree_from_root(node* in_root);

int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
    binary_tree tree_1;
    init_tree(tree_1);
    insert_node(10,tree_1);
    insert_node(30,tree_1);
    insert_node(40,tree_1);
    insert_node(20,tree_1);
    insert_node(50,tree_1);
    print_tree_from_root(tree_1.root);
}
void init_tree(binary_tree& in_tree)
{
    in_tree.root = NULL;
}
node* create_new_node(int data)
{
    node* temp = new node;
    temp->data = data;
    temp->left_linker = NULL;
    temp->right_linker = NULL;
    return temp;
}
void insert_node(int in_data,binary_tree& in_tree)
{
    if(tree_empty(in_tree))
    {
        in_tree.root = create_new_node(in_data);
    }
    else
    {
        insert_recursively(in_data,in_tree.root);
    }
}

node* insert_recursively(int in_data,node* in_root)
{
    if(in_root == 0)
    {
        in_root = create_new_node(in_data);
        return in_root;
    }
    else
    {
        if(in_data > in_root->data)
        {
            in_root->right_linker = insert_recursively(in_data,in_root->right_linker);
        }
        else if(in_data < in_root->data)
        {
            in_root->left_linker = insert_recursively(in_data,in_root->left_linker);
        }
    }
}

bool tree_empty(binary_tree& in_tree)
{
    if(in_tree.root == 0)
        return true;
    return false;
}

void print_tree_from_root(node* in_root)
{
    if(in_root == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<in_root->data<<endl;
        print_tree_from_root(in_root->left_linker);
        print_tree_from_root(in_root->right_linker);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't post code as a picture. Create a [mcve] and post that as text.

Comment: Don't forget to tag with a language (I guess C++?) and actually *ask a question* when you do.

Comment: it's not all about the code, the problem is the editor, in VisualStudio, the result above is not right

Comment: If you really think Visual Studio is at fault, we cannot help you. We can only help with *your* code. But chances are, the bug *is* in your code.

Comment: It is c++ or c? I edited the question to remove the image and insert the actual code. @nvoigt (As a comment to your first comment)

Comment: @Edric while I applaud the fact that you improved the question, ultimately even typed out code is worthless if it's not a [mcve].

Comment: @nvoigt I guess so....

Comment: it has only some functions ,I did name them to understand more easily

Comment: and I posted complete code

Comment: @HoàngĐẹpTrai You didn't. Include a MCVE into your question please.

Comment: This isn't complete code, it wouldn't compile otherwise. But obviously there's a bug in your `insert_node` function, which you haven't shown us

Comment: I tested it in codeblock and there was no bug, but when I copy into a new VS project, it showed only 2 numbers, I don't know why

Comment: Most likely there is a bug in your code. But it is not possible to tell unless you post code here. Not image, not random link, not GitHub link, but actual code as text.

Comment: ok, so let me edit the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`insert_recursively` does not return a value when it goes into `else` block however you store the returned value (garbage) in `right_linker` or `left_linker` anyway.

Note that compiler issues a corresponding warning:

> warning C4715: 'insert_recursively': not all control paths return a value

Comment: I figured out the problem, thanks, but I still do not understand why CodeBlocks printed all the values